# Best way to integrate blockchain to web app

Tags: tokens, dapp-development, faucets

I am developing this web app to track work with the hopes of integrating the blockchain to record it. The user would submit data through a form and each node hopes to track both users, amount of credit transferred, type of work and timestamp of work. I've seen a lot of users use Metamask to interface but I don't want that.

The setup I have in mind is in my smart contract, it creates an object around a custom token (not nfts or anything, just a variable) and the account that deploys it acts as an admin account and has the total number of custom tokens. When users sign up, the admin gives them a base amount of credits to do work and gain more credits from other users too. Ideally, I want the users to able to operate through the application without having to connect to wallets (e.g all the blockchain work is being done in the background).

Some questions relating to this:

1. How would users that sign up have an address to transfer credits to and from?
2. How can users take care of gas prices during each transactions? I had hoped the admin account could pay for it but it doesn't seem possible from what I am reading.
3. My current setup is to have 2 smart contracts with 1 being the tokens and the 2nd having the user data as well as the tokens. Is it better to have 1 or 2 smart contracts?
4. When the admin deploys the contract, I was going to use a faucet to supply them initially to transfer the tokens to other users signing up. Is it wise to use a faucet or is there another way?

Sorry if I'm mixing any of the terminology, I'm very much new to this.